# How to use asp.net identity cookie auth along with oidcconnect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses ASP.NET Identity 2/OWIN that has it's own login using the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString(AppConfiguration.LoginPath),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), 
                        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                        getUserIdCallback: (id) => (Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId())))
                }
            });
```

In Addition to our own authentication set up above in the startup, we'd like to also introduce authentication using an external app that uses Identity Server 4 (basically just so a user in that app can sso into ours), using open id connect, setting that up after the above code like:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = AppConfiguration.ExternalServerAuthority,
                ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxx",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:1045/signin-oidc",
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:1045/signout-callback-oidc",
               SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {                  
SecurityTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        var appAuthManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IApplicationAuthenticationManager>();
                        var userManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IApplicationUserManager>();

                        var email = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username");

                        var user = userManager.FindByName(email.Value, null);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                         await appAuthManager.SignInAsync(user, false, false);
    }

}
});
```

We need to be able to do a SignInAsync when we get the token from the external app because we need the user to be signed in as the actual user in our own app.  Part of our problem is also, if we set this up, then whenever a user is not logged in, they are always sent to the other external app to log in if trying to access a resource/page that they must be logged in for - it no longer sends them to our existing login page (which would give them the option of logging in there like they normally would or clicking a link to take them to the other app to log in if they have a user account for that app too).  We don't want this because not all our users will be using/have access to this other app, it's really only for some users, mostly to conveniently navigate into our app from the other app without having to separately sign in to ours.  So we can't have all unauthorized requests sent to this other app to log in.  How can we achieve that?  Is there a better way to set that up here?

Edit for more info:

To explain more clearly the pieces here and what needs to happen.  There are actually three applications at play.  There is our app, an MVC 5 app that has it's own login page, uses owin/asp.net identity for user authentication and to store/manage its users.  There is now another app (for another company that wants to work with us), which is a SPA app that authenticates against a separate IdentityServer4 server run by the same company.  This SPA app, wants to put a link in it that sends a user to our MVC 5 app without the user having to actually log in to our MVC 5 app - so, they want to SSO into our MVC 5 app (by use setting up our app to use oidc connect to authenticate the user against the SPA's identity server).  So when they get to our app, we need to actually log them in as our user....but we have to also make sure that all our users are not sent to this external app to log in when they are not currently logged in to our app because not all our users will have access to this external app.  I hope that clears this up.

Comment: in this case IDS would be the external login. did you try IDS as passive authentication? like what we do for external logins? [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication/EmbeddedMvc) for external login

Comment: Hi - thanks for helping me again! I thought maybe this should be a separate question from my last one. I tried to set AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive in the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions, but doing that seems to cause it to never check with the external IDS server/app at all if the user is logged in there.  More context: we want to have a link in the external app that takes the person to our app without having to log in. The ext app is a spa that uses a separate IDS server for auth, so our mvc app needs to auth with that IDS server, even though the user comes from the spa.

Comment: np! The question is bit unclear to me, here is what I understood so far(correct me if I’m wrong):
1. Components are SPA-app, MVC4-app and IDS4
2. SPA-app has its own login, it needs to SSO to MVC5-app
3. MVC5-app has 2 authentication mechanisms. cookie auth and also OIDC for IDS4
If these are correct, can you re-phrase your question in this context? @user1368182

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I'll update my original post and see if I can explain better in terms of that.  Thanks!

Comment: what you ask is a IDP initiated SSO to me. this is not supported in OIDC as much as I know. I did similar thing using SAML2.0 before though.

Comment: I see, ok - so even the code I have above would not work then.  Ok, I'll look into SAML then.  Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You can definitely put some more effort on the POC. Only tip is to use external cookie for SSO(OIDC in mvc app), to keep the main login as well as SSO

Comment: Ok, I see how to make this work - I can have a button on both my app's login screen that goes to an externallogin action that issues a challenge result for my provider name (which is whatever I call their app), and they can have a link in their app that goes to the same externallogin action, specifying their app name as the provider (so same link basically), which will send them to my app, which will in turn check with their app that the person is logged in, and if so, send them back to my callback and I can look up the user and sign them in.

Comment: I just need to let them know what our callback/redirect uri is to make sure they call back into that on our app after successfuly auth, and then this should work.  (I did still set up the connect options in my app as Passive too, since I didn't want my app to just automatically send users to the other app when not logged in).